# product collection toolbar with request params in magento custom module

Tags: php, codeblocks, magento-1.9

[image]

[image]

I have a filter named CARTRIDGE FINDER. When I click button,FIND MY CARTRIDGE by selecting printer series dropdown, then it shows product collection with product list toolbar correctly and nicely. But when I sort by name or price or view as list, it shows There are no products matching the selection. Here my custom (manufacturer) module's layout file's code is given below:

```
<manufacturer_index_filter>
  <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
  </reference>
<reference name="content">
       <block type="manufacturer/custom" name="printer_filter" template="manufacturer/brand_filter_result.phtml"/> 
</reference>
```

And the code of module's (manufacturer) block file, Custom.php is given below:`class Bubmania_Manufacturer_Block_Custom extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();$printer = $this->getRequest()->getParams();$make_a_printer_op_val = $printer['make_a_printer'];$printer_series = $printer['printer_series'];
        $printer_model_no = $printer['printer_model_no'];

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*'); 
    $collection->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter(array(
        array('attribute'=>'manufacturer','eq'=>$make_a_printer_op_val),
        array('attribute'=>'printerseries','eq'=>$printer_series), 
        array('attribute'=>'printermodelnumber','eq'=>$printer_model_no),
    ));
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);$this->setCollection($collection); /* parent::__construct();

    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
               ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', array(
                           Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                           Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
               )); //showing just products visible in catalog or both search and catalog
        $this->setCollection($collection); */}
```

protected function _prepareLayout(){
        parent::_prepareLayout();

```
    //$toolbar = $this->getToolbarBlock();
    $toolbar = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_list')->getToolbarBlock();

    // called prepare sortable parameters
    $collection = $this->getCollection();

    // use sortable parameters
    if ($orders = $this->getAvailableOrders()) {
        $toolbar->setAvailableOrders($orders);
    }
    if ($sort = $this->getSortBy()) {
        $toolbar->setDefaultOrder($sort);
    }
    if ($dir = $this->getDefaultDirection()) {
        $toolbar->setDefaultDirection($dir);
    }
    $toolbar->setCollection($collection);

    $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
    $this->getCollection()->load();
    return $this;
}public function getDefaultDirection(){
    return 'asc';
}
```

public function getAvailableOrders(){
        //return array('created_time'=> 'Created Time','update_time'=>'Updated Time','collection_id'=>'ID', 'name'=>'Name');
        return array('name'=> 'Name','position'=>'Position','price'=>'Price'); 
    }
    public function getSortBy(){
        return 'name';
    }
    public function getToolbarBlock()
    {
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('manufacturer/toolbar', microtime());
        return $block;
    }
    public function getMode()
    {
        return $this->getChild('toolbar')->getCurrentMode();
    }

```
public function getToolbarHtml()
{
    return $this->getChildHtml('toolbar');
}}`
```

But when It runs only with Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection(), not params, then it runs successfully with product collection toolbar. I need to set params in this toolbar. How to do this. If any one knows this point, please reply me as soon as possible. I have googled a lot. But there is no a specific result.
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Try extending:

```
class CollectionFilter extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\CollectionFilter
{

public function filter(
    $collection,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category
) {
if(isset($_GET['your filter']))

/* your magic here*/
```

Comment: The question was marked as magento 1.9, your answer seems to be for Magento 2.x. Also, using $_GET directly is against Magento's best practices.